# Configuring WWan LTE modem (SIM7000a)

Tags: networking, modem

Does anyone have any experience hooking up a WWAN? I picked up a SIM7000A and re-activated one of my AT&T hotspot sims to work with it. This particular one is a PCIE card but came with a PCIE to USB adapter. I'm currently trying to get it working on my Ubuntu 18.04 but was hoping to use it with one of my pi's. On the USB adapter if possible as I can built a relay to 'turn off' power to it when not needed.

I can post more details if needed. I was trying to set it up using various examples I could find online using nmcli. I can see the device on mmcli and found an app called modem-manager gui and it also sees it and can even see SMS messages sent to the card/number after activating it. But it says it is waiting for registration on the network to do anything else.

dmesg shows it being set up as a wwan0 before being re-named to a unique name. Trying ifconfig {name} up doesn't work. using nmcli to try to bring it up says timeout waiting for network registration or something along those line.

I want to set up one of my pis as a dual purpose box. When hunting season comes around, I'd love to connect it up via the cellular to check cameras and sensors around my deer blind (just because I can). The rest of the year, I'd prefer to use this (or at least 'a') modem connected to my raspberry pi as a hotspot when I'm up north.

There have also been some thefts recently in the storage area up there, and as a third possible option, I'd love to set it up with motion sensors to alert me in real time if anyone is sniffing around my RV when I'm not there!

```
$ mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/9 [QUALCOMM INCORPORATED] 0
$ mmcli -m 9
  --------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/9
           |            device id: 38e1ce95f270fd9760a2f3ece20a2f6b00bbd989
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                model: 0
           |             revision: MPSS.JO.3.0.2.c3-00017-9607_LTEONLY_PACK-1  1  [Jul 25 2017 12:00:00]
           |         h/w revision: 10000
           |            supported: lte
           |              current: lte
           |         equipment id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb7/7-1
           |              drivers: qmi_wwan, option1
           |               plugin: SimTech
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm1
           |                ports: ttyUSB0 (qcdm), wwp0s16f1u1i5 (net), ttyUSB3 (at), 
           |                       cdc-wdm1 (qmi), ttyUSB2 (at)
  --------------------------------
  Numbers  |                  own: 1734xxxxxxx
  --------------------------------
  Status   |                 lock: sim-pin2
           |       unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)
           |                state: enabled
           |          power state: on
           |       signal quality: 0% (cached)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |              current: allowed: 4g; preferred: none
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-12, eutran-13
           |              current: eutran-2, eutran-4, eutran-12, eutran-13
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-1
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/9

$ sudo nmcli dev status
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
eno1        ethernet  connected     Wired connection 1 
wlp3s0      wifi      connected     Auto MYSSID
cdc-wdm1    modem     disconnected  --                 
lo          loopback  unmanaged     --                 

$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ATT\ Wireless 
[connection]
id=ATT Wireless
uuid=90314301-ed3b-4666-a505-9b64017bd081
interface-name=wwp0s16f1u1i5
type=gsm
metered=1
permissions=

[gsm]
apn=phone
number=*99#

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

$ nmcli c up "ATT Wireless"Error: Connection activation failed: Network registration timed out
```

Any help getting this thing up and going is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot see, where a Raspberry Pi is involved. If your dongle works then you should just find an interface, e.g. usb0 or ppp0 or sometihing else. What operating system do you use? Raspbian does support Network Manager.

Comment: well, the intention is to implement this on a pi. The pi in question is just difficult to get to so I would prefer to confirm the device is working before installing it permanently in the remote system. i.e. anything I get working on ubuntu must also work similarly on the pi.